# movzbl on a string to a register

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, mov

I'm trying to read through assembly lines and deciphering what they do, and I got this far:

%eax is currently 70, and is about to be overwritten

%ebx is a string I inputted, consisting of 70 "m"s. Its address is 0x804d850, and continues through 0x804d896 as the terminating character. All the addresses inbetween have the value 109 for m.

This is the line I got stuck on:

```
0x0804927b <+39>:    movzbl  (%ebx), %eax
0x0804927e <+42>:    test    %al, %al
```

From what I understand, I'm trying to move a byte from my string to overwrite %eax, and then zero extend it. Then I'm comparing the lowest byte of %eax (The 'm' that just movzbl'd) to zero.

How is it that I can get %al to be equal to 0? Isn't that corresponding to the NULL character? If I input that as my 70th character for the string, the string would just be 69 characters long instead, and it would still take an 'm' off the end.

Sorry if this question is worded in a confusing fashion.

Comment: Yes, `test %al,%al` will set ZF only if `%ebx` is pointing to the`\0` byte that terminates an implicit-length C string.  This looks like it's just checking for the end of the string, assuming the next instruction is a `jz` or `jnz` or similar.  Presumably this is in a loop that increments EBX.

Comment: Well, that answered my question, I wish I could accept it. It's a loop and I failed to see it until I kept reading. It increments %ebx and compares it to another string, letter by letter, until it reaches the end. My issue was that I thought movzbl took the last letter of the string, when in reality it took the first letter.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because it wasn't clear there was even a coherent question.  `movzbl` is like `mov`, except it zero-extends the low byte to 32-bits (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html).  It doesn't somehow scan a string for you to find the end.  That explains why the question was so confusing.